# Does an inflatable heat shield have some capacity to be used for LEO Earth's atmospheric entry?

Tags: reentry, heat-shield, heat

It was originally designed and tested by NASA for Mars missions.
In my case, it does not have to work 100%. Even if it survives for only 1 minute or so, during atmospheric entry - it could add some value to an asteroid mining mission.

[image]

Comment: I am looking for a way to decrease the chances of a 100-ton metallic asteroid (piece from it) breaking apart during atmospheric entry.

Comment: @GremlinWranger - good question. I was not thinking about that part. I thought Earth's gravity assist will be sufficient to get on LEO.

Comment: @GremlinWranger -  thank you very much. Do you think I will be ridiculed if I bring up the option of using an inflatable heat shield in Earth's atmosphere? Some people tell me that this is a nonstarter, because it was designed for a thinner  Mars atmosphere.

Comment: @GremlinWranger - Thank you!!! I am updating my article accordingly.

Comment: While I appreciate the accepted answer tick, it is generally a good idea to wait at least 24 hours for people in other timezones to have a look, it may turn out there are newer/better design studies or that I completely malfunctioned the math.

Comment: @GremlinWranger - You were very generous. The details you've provided and the reference to "Advanced European Re-Entry System" were very important for my article.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For LEO the answer appears to be a qualified yes.

This [design study](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/349217239_Advanced_European_Re-Entry_System_Based_on_Inflatable_Heat_Shields_Detailed_Design_EFESTO_project) looks at recovering the [150 kg Vega upper stage](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vega_(rocket)) using a 4.5 meter diameter system. Scaling for area to get 100 tonnes that looks like a 50 meter radius.

This is notably larger than the 100 tonne space shuttle orbiter with a 23 meter wingspan, due to the larger heat flux that could be tolerated. If a more robust design is possible the area can probably be reduced closer to the 37 by 23 meter shuttle.

Engineering a 50 meter structure that is inflatable is probably not possible but assuming robotic or human assembly presumably already required to load the asteroid into the system a flat pack solution using the same flexible heat shield surface with an assembled supporting structure probably is achievable, possibly also allowing a higher heat loading and therefore smaller dimensions.